# Mock a method that will return different results based on the order that it's called

Tags: mocking, phpunit, expectations

I would like to mock a method that returns `A` when first called, and `B` when called the second time, and all subsequent calls to it will return `C`. I was assuming that I can use `$this->any()` and `$this->at()` to get the desired expectation, but it seems `$this->any()` will always take precedence.

```
// calls to foo() will always return 'C' even after the following setup
$this->expects($this->any())->method('foo')->will($this->returnValue('C'));
$this->expects($this->at(0))->method('foo')->will($this->returnValue('A'));
$this->expects($this->at(1))->method('foo')->will($this->returnValue('B'));
```

Are there ways to do this?

Answer (score 3):

I think the any() is the problem.  I believe you want

```
$this->expects($this->at(0))->method('foo')->will($this->returnValue('A'));
$this->expects($this->at(1))->method('foo')->will($this->returnValue('B'));
$this->expects($this->at(2))->method('foo')->will($this->returnValue('C'));
```

Since you control the tests, you do not need to do any more calls, or add additional at() references.

Another option is the withConsecutive() method which can take any number of arrays of arguments ([PHPUnit Mock Objects Manual](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.mock-objects)).

From the Manual:

```
$mock = $this->getMock('stdClass', array('set'));
$mock->expects($this->exactly(2))
     ->method('set')
     ->withConsecutive(
         array($this->equalTo('foo'), $this->greaterThan(0)),
         array($this->equalTo('bar'), $this->greaterThan(0))
     );

$mock->set('foo', 21);
$mock->set('bar', 48);
```

Note the warning about the at() calls as it does tie testing to implementation details quite tightly.

Comment: I didn't want to remove the any() because my method is called in a loop, and removing that will require me to use at() repeatedly which I didn't want to do... But thanks for the information on ```withConsecutive()```!